# The meaning of 나는 네가 아는것을 안다

Tags: grammar, verb

I try to understand how will "I know that you know" and "I know what you know" be translated.

In both cases I would say 나는 네가 아는것을 안다, but as I am a newbie, I guess I am wrong.

How these kind of sentences will be distinguished?

Comment: Uh, hold on, `north-korean`?

Comment: The tag was placed because I considered the northern version being different from the nornal version.

Comment: Right, but, I mean, sorry, I didn't see the tag when I answered. My answer is based on the south one. Though it'd work in the north, too, I guess?

Comment: I think it will work for the north too, because the word 사실 is used in the DPRK too. There are 2 differences. 아는것 is written without space and maybe 아는가 would be used instead of 아는지.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how I should put this, so let me just give you possible constructions, both ambiguous ones and not.

## I know

> 나는 안다.
>
> I know.

- Pronoun “나” ― I.
- Marker “는” ― A subject marker.
- Verb “알다” ― To know.
- Ending conjugation “-ᆫ다” ― Describing the current status or fact.

> 나는 ……을/를 안다.
>
> I know …….

- Marker “을/를” ― An object marker.

---

## (things) that you know

> 네가 무엇을 아는지
>
> What you know

- Pronoun “네” ― The variation of “너” before “가,” meaning “you.”
- Marker “가” ― A subject marker.
- Pronoun “무엇” ― What.
- Conjugation “-는지” ― An indirect question marker: whether, if; who, what, where, how.

---

> 네가 아는 것 [ambiguous]
>
> things that you know (“what you know”); the fact that you know. [ambiguous]

- En-modifier conjugation “-는” ― A conjugation forming a modifier clause.
- Dependent noun “것” ― A thing; a fact that.

> 네가 아는 사실 [ambiguous]
>
> The fact which you know, the fact that you know [ambiguous]

- Noun “사실” ― A fact.

---

> 네가 ……을/를 아는 것
>
> The fact that you know ……

> 네가 ……을/를 아는 사실
>
> The fact that you know ……

---

> 네가 안다는 것 (‘네가 안다’는 것)
>
> The fact that “you know”

- Conjugation “-ᆫ다는” ― “that,” implying quoting.

> 네가 안다는 사실 (‘네가 안다’는 사실)
>
> The fact that “you know”

---

> 네가 ……을/를 안다는 것 (‘네가 ……을/를 안다’는 것)
>
> The fact that “you know …….”

> 네가 ……을/를 안다는 사실 (‘네가 ……을/를 안다’는 사실)
>
> The fact that “you know …….”

---

## Full sentences

> 나는 네가 무엇을 아는지(를) 안다. [The most clear sentence]
>
> I know what you know. [The most clear sentence]

---

> 나는 네가 아는 것을 안다. [ambiguous, but it often means “I know what you know.”]
>
> I know what you know; I know that you know. [ambiguous, but it often means “I know what you know.”]

> 나는 네가 아는 사실을 안다. [ambiguous, but it often means “I know what you know.”]
>
> I know what you know; I know that you know. [ambiguous, but it often means “I know what you know.”]

---

> 나는 네가 ……을/를 아는 것을 안다.
>
> I know that you know …….

> 나는 네가 ……을/를 아는 사실을 안다.
>
> I know that you know …….

---

> 나는 네가 안다는 것을 안다.
>
> I know that “you know.”

> 나는 네가 안다는 사실을 안다.
>
> I know that “you know.”

---

> 나는 네가 ……을/를 안다는 것을 안다.
>
> I know that “you know …….”

> 나는 네가 ……을/를 안다는 사실을 안다.  [The most clear sentence]
>
> I know that “you know …….”  [The most clear sentence]

Answer (score 1):

You can be more specific with the object in which 'you know'

> I know that you know -> 나는 네가 그것을 아는것을 안다.

The object here is `that`, so you'll need to add the phrase to `그것을`.

> I know what you know -> 나는 네가 무었을 아는것을 안다

You're specifically wanting to know `what`. `What` is `무엇`. We are focusing the object to `what` in the previous statement.

Like in English you want to add direct objects to address what the verb is saying.

Comment: Wouldn't "I know what you know" be  나는 네가 무엇을 아는**지** 안다?